# How to make a well balanced diet?

Tags: nutrition, diet

There is so much bogus information on "how" to eat that its overwhelming. So i have a couple questions. What would the perfect diet look like (not carrying about actual type of food just its make up)? For instance would it be 50% protein, 30% carbs ... you get the idea.

As to the percentages would you want to adjust these throughout the day? More protein say early am and less at night?

Are eggs good or bad? I am really sick of this one. I love eggs and in one study they are perfectly fine to eat even everyday and in others you should limit them. In another just the whites, and yet again in another it doesn't matter.

Getting ready to start a new workout routine and diet. Quit smoking after 20 years and finally feel like trying to get in shape but i am trying to weed through all the information and its proving more overwhelming then I could have anticipated.

Edit: 
How do these things change when planning a meal for a workout and does the workout meal take place before the workout or after. Lastly how long before/after should the meal take place?

Comment: You should find the answer to your question about eggs [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/921/egg-whites-and-yolks). Egg whites are pretty much universally accepted as healthy. Personally, I think that egg yolks are just as good but peruse the linked question and decide for yourself.

Comment: At the time this was originally posted, nutrition was considered on topic. Now nutrition is very narrowly focused, please do not take this question as an example of what is currently allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tend to carry your weight only around your midsection, you may lose weight more effectively by cutting back somewhat on carbohydrates, especially the highly processed or sugary carbohydrates. If you tend to carry your extra weight more uniformly, cutting back on overall calories is the best approach, and reducing fat intake is the easiest way to cut calories.

Ive been reading a few recent studies, one of them show that when a majority of calories are consumed in the p.m. that there test subjects lost more bodyfat than the a.m. test group. They also tested exercises with the test group in the pm and am, the second part of the results show it's better to work out in the p.m.

This other study showed eating all your carbs before 12pm had a big impact on body fat.

Breaking up your meals to 5 times a day is also important, it boosts your metabolism and it helps burn calories through thermogenesis

So i suggest eating 5 times a day. 50% protein(lean cuts and eggs) 40% carbs (vegetables) and 10% fat. No wheat, potatoes, beer, fried foods or sugar. eating most of your carbs in the morning time. You also need to reduce carbs if most of your weight is in your mid section or lower calories if your body fat is mostly evenly spread through out.

Calories should be around 15x body weight if your trying to loss weight and your on a strength workout program like i wrote or it should be around 13-14x body weight if your body fat is spread evenly through out.

Lastly it really doesnt matter much when you time your meals around your workouts as long as your eating 5 times a day. I never worry about timing around workouts and i gain muscle and strength fine cause your always moving food thru your gut.

Leave me a comment if this is'nt what your looking for.

Comment: Please link to the studies you reference.